# Proof of a formula related to permutations and combinations involving geometrical figures

Tags: permutations, combinations

How to prove that the number of triangles that can be formed by joining the angular points of a polygon of n sides as vertices are$\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}$?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6} = \frac{n!}{3! \cdot (n-3)!} = {n \choose 3}$$

Comment: I get your hint.Thanks :)